# Speed up mongorestore rebuilding indexes

Tags: mongodb

I'm restoring a database from `mongodump` with `mongorestore` and it takes hours. Most of this time is spent building indexes on large collections.

Is there any option of `mongodump` or `mongorestore` I can use to speed things up?

Answer (score 4):

You could try the [--noIndexRestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption--noIndexRestore) option of mongorestore, and then create the [indexes later in background](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/build-indexes-in-the-background/).